# Is it possible to describe this situation with one sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

How to describe this situation with one sentence:

> My friend and I submitted our paper to A and B journals, respectively.
> But unfortunately, both papers got rejected by the respective journal.
> Then, my friend and I resubmitted our paper to B and A journals,
> respectively. This time, both papers got accepted.

One sentence summary: Our papers got accepted by the journal that rejected ...??

Comment: "Our papers were both rejected by different journals, but when each of us tried the other journal, both were accepted."

Comment: thank you, but it seems lost the information that the 'other journal' is the one I/my friend tried and failed before

Comment: ***Each** of our papers was [subsequently] accepted by the journal that **had previously rejected the other's [paper]***. Or perhaps better, ***Both of our papers were...***

Comment: OK. It seemed clear to me that _each tried the other_ means _not the one that had previously rejected us_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My friend and I submitted our paper to A and B journals, respectively. But unfortunately, both papers got rejected by the respective journal. Then, my friend and I resubmitted our paper to B and A journals, respectively. This time, both papers got accepted.

You could re-write this in one sentence as either:

> Papers submitted by my friend and me to two different journals respectively were rejected, but when we each submitted to the corresponding journal, both were accepted.

or, more succinctly, but reliant on a good understanding of the situation:

> Our papers were accepted by the journals that previously rejected the other person's.

Comment: _By my friend and me_, surely? (We wouldn't say _by I_.)

Comment: @KateBunting Yeah, I was being extra polite.